# How to use rename_with() in pipe to change all column names from vector

Tags: r, dplyr

I want to apply new column names from a vector to a dataframe.

There are already good answers to this question:
[Applying dplyr's rename to all columns while using pipe operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34092237/applying-dplyrs-rename-to-all-columns-while-using-pipe-operator/56304086), [How do I add a prefix to several variable names using dplyr?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33741357/how-do-i-add-a-prefix-to-several-variable-names-using-dplyr)

My question is explicitly:
What is the equivalent of rename_with to this:

```
newcolnames <- c("one", "two", "three", "four", "five")

head(iris) %>% 
  setNames(newcolnames)

head(iris) %>% 
  `colnames<-`(newcolnames)
```

I tried:

```
head(iris) %>% 
  rename_with(iris, newcolnames)
```

I want to use explicitly `rename_with`!

Comment: Can you please clarify _why_ you want to use `rename_with` when you already have a vector with new column names. I assume you know that `rename_with` needs a `.fn` argument: "A function used to transform the selected `.cols`". Cheers

Comment: It is mainly for learning purposes. I am still learning. Within this process I develop an idea. Then I try to apply this idea to practice by doing some research. And if I don't find a solution like in this case it was not possible for me to grasp exactly this function need of `rename_with`, I ask a question here. Thank you for reply.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't seem like `rename_with` is the right function for this. I guess you could do

```
iris %>% 
  rename_with(~newcolnames)
```

as kind of a hack. You can also use `rename`

```
iris %>% 
  rename(!!!setNames(names(.), newcolnames))
```

But the `setNames` method just seems much more apt.

Comment: Ok. That is what I was exactly looking for. So the vector is becoming a function by ~?

Comment: `~` makes it a formula, which the tidyverse treats as a kind of anonymous function. Note that this isn't true for R in general.

Comment: @Migwell Thank you very much. Now it is much more clearer for me. The `with` part in `rename_with` refers to the fact that this function needs a function that will be applied to each column of the dataframe and how a vector could fulfill this request. Now I understand why people downvoted my question. But for me it was not logical to have a function that renames column names, but is not able to rename the column names that are stored in a vector.